# Does Coverity support Angular2 and above version?

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, automation, coverity

Does coverity supports angular2 and the above versions?

If yes then whats the process for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is **NO**. Coverity supports only **AngularJS 1.x**, no support for TypeScript as of now (June 20, 2018).

Check [here](https://community.synopsys.com/s/question/0D53400003uxKTsCAM/does-coverity-support-angularjs-20) official information